# Rails - How to make Will-Paginate links show up BELOW the table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I just came across the `will-paginate` gem. I'm trying to separate records into multiple pages. I managed to make some progress, but I ran into a problem.

The Pagination Tab (that shows the page numbers) appears above the table. It is also uncentered. How can I have the tab appear below the table.

This is how it currently looks

```
                          <= Previous 1 2 Next =>
                                 Table Data
```

How I would like it to look

```
                                 Table Data
                           <= Previous 1 2 Next =>
```

Here is my code

```
<tbody>

  <% g = Game.where(console: @title.split(' ').first(2).join(' ')).order(title: :asc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2) %>
    <% g.each do |game| %>
    <tr>
      <td> <%= link_to "#{game.title}", game %></td>
      <td> <%= game.genre %></td>
      <td> <%= game.release_date %></td>
      <td> <%= game.rating %></td>

      <% if signed_in? && current_user.admin? %>

      <div>
        <td id = 'actions'><%= link_to 'Show', game, class: 'action' %></td>
        <td id = 'actions'><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_game_path(game), class: 'action' %></td>
        <td id = 'actions'><%= link_to 'Delete', game, method: :delete, class: 'action' %></td>
      </div>

      <% end %>

    </tr>

    <%= will_paginate g %>

  <% end %>

</tbody>
```

I even put `will_paginate` at the end of my code block.

Comment: From where do you get `Table Data`? will_paginate puts by default the left/right arrow + page number.

Comment: The table data is my table. I'd like the pagination links to show up below the table

Comment: Try with `<tr><%= will_paginate g %></tr>`

Comment: Also, it's not valid to have `div` in `tr` and you have the same `id` for multiple elements.

Comment: Pagination header still shows up above the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is invalid. Your call to will_paginate is inside of the table, in between tags.

If you want it to show up below, above, or anywhere else, just put the call to pagination there.

```
<%= will_paginate collection %>
```

You really should be instantiating instance variables in your controller. This line should not be in your view.

```
<% g = Game.where(console: # ...
```

This way you solve the restriction of where to place your pagination call, and you write more idiomatic Rails code.

If you must go down this road, and I strongly discourage you, just do load your collection above the table.

```
<% g = Game.where(console: @title.split(' ').first(2).join(' ')).order(title: :asc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2) %>
```

Then, below that, render the pagination since the variable `g` now exists:

```
<%= will_paginate g %>
```

Then render your table.

Comment: This actually isn't my view. It's a partial that is rendered in my views.

Comment: Partials are reusable views. So it's still a view. And what's the point of having a partial if you can't reuse it? Clean it up and load the collection from the controller. It's better.

Comment: Well that actually works. I ended up having to declare `g` outside of the table in the actual view. And also `will_paginate` in the same view. Thanks